# Attempt to assign property "SKU" on null

Tags: php, laravel, null

I'm trying to create new data.
I have the error massage if I submit this page.
Please, give me advice. thank you for all.
if i delete $Product -> SKU = $this->SKU; on AdminAddProductComponent.php, the error has gone.

my web.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Http\Livewire\User\UserDashboardComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\Admin\AdminDashboardComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\Admin\AdminCategoryComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\Admin\AdminAddCategoryComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\Admin\AdminEditCategoryComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\Admin\AdminProductComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\Admin\AdminAddProductComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\Admin\AdminEditProductComponent;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

// Route::get('/', function () {
//     return view('welcome');
// });

Route::get('/',HomeComponent::class);

Route::get('/shop',ShopComponent::class);
Route::get('/cart',CartComponent::class)->name('product.cart');
Route::get('/checkout',CheckoutComponent::class);
Route::get('/product/{slug}',DetailComponent::class)->name('product.details');
Route::get('/product-category/{category_slug}',CategoryComponent::class)->name('product.category');
Route::get('/search',SearchComponent::class)->name('product.search');

//Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
//    return view('dashboard');
//})->name('dashboard');

//For User or Customer
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum','verified'])->group(function(){
    Route::get('/user/dashboard',UserDashboardComponent::class)->name('user.dashboard');
});

//For Admin
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum','verified','authadmin'])->group(function(){
    Route::get('/admin/dashboard',AdminDashboardComponent::class)->name('admin.dashboard');
    Route::get('/admin/categories',AdminCategoryComponent::class)->name('admin.categories');
    Route::get('/admin/category/add',AdminAddCategoryComponent::class)->name('admin.addcategory');
    Route::get('/admin/category/edit/{category_slug}',AdminEditCategoryComponent::class)->name('admin.editcategory');
    Route::get('/admin/products',AdminProductComponent::class)->name('admin.products');
    Route::get('/admin/product/add',AdminAddProductComponent::class)->name('admin.addproduct');
    Route::get('/admin/product/edit/{product_slug}',AdminEditProductComponent::class)->name('admin.editproduct');


});
```

my product migration table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateProductsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->string('short_description')->nullable();
            $table->text('description');
            $table->decimal('regular_price');
            $table->decimal('sale_price')->nullable();
            $table->string('SKU');
            $table->enum('stock_status',['instock','outofstock']);
            $table->boolean('featured')->default(false);
            $table->unsignedInteger('quantity')->default(10);
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->text('images')->nullable();
            $table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->bigInteger('add_info_weight')->nullable();
            $table->string('add_info_dimensions')->nullable();
            $table->string('add_info_color')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
}
```

This is my AdminAddProductCompmnent.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Category;
use App\Models\Product;
use illuminate\Support\Str;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;

class AdminAddProductComponent extends Component
{
    use WithFileuploads;
    public $name;
    public $slug;
    public $short_description;
    public $description;
    public $regular_price;
    public $sale_price;
    public $SKU;
    public $stock_status;
    public $featured;
    public $quantity;
    public $image;
    public $category_id;
    public $add_info_weight;
    public $add_info_dimensions;
    public $add_info_color;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->stock_status = 'instock';
        $this->featured = 0;
   
    }

    public function generateSlug()
    {
        $this->slug = Str::slug($this->name,'-');
    }

    public function addProduct()
    {
        $Product = new Product();
        $Product->name = $this->name;
        $Product->slug = $this->slug;
        $Product->short_description = $this->short_description;
        $Product->description = $this->description;
        $Product->regular_price = $this->regular_price;
        $Product->sale_price = $this->sale_price;
        $product->SKU = $this->SKU;
        $Product->stock_status = $this->stock_status;
        $Product->featured = $this->featured;
        $Product->quantity = $this->quantity;
        $imageName = Carbon::now() ->timestamp. '.' . $this ->image->extension();
        $this->image->storeAs('products',$imageName);
        $Product->image = $imageName;
        $Product->category_id = $this->category_id;
        $Product->add_info_weight = $this->add_info_weight;
        $Product->add_info_dimensions = $this->add_info_dimensions;
        $Product->add_info_color = $this->add_info_color;
        $Product->save();
        session()->flash('message','Product has been created successfully');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $categories = Category::all();
        return view('livewire.admin.admin-add-product-component',['categories'=> $categories])->layout('layouts.base');
    }
}
```

This is my admin-add-product-component.blade.php

```
<div>
    <div class="container" style="padding: 30px 0;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <b>Add New Product</b>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <a href="{{ route('admin.products')}}" class="btn btn-success pull-right">All Products</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        @if(Session::has('message'))
                            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">{{Session::get('message')}}</div>
                        @endif
                        <form class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" wire:submit.prevent="addProduct">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Product Name</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Product Name" class="form-control input-md" wire:model="name" wire:keyup="generateSlug"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Product Slug</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Product Slug" class="form-control input-md" wire:model="slug"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Short Description</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Short Description" wire:model="short_description">
                                    </textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Description</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Description" wire:model="description">
                                    </textarea>                 
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Regular Price</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Regular Price" class="form-control input-md" wire:model="regular_price"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Sale Price</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Sale Price" class="form-control input-md" wire:model="sale_price"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">SKU</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="SKU" class="form-control input-md" wire:model="SKU"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Stock</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <select class="form-control" wire:model="stock_status">
                                        <option value="instock">Instock</option>
                                        <option value="outofstock">Out of stock</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Featured</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <select class="form-control" wire:model="featured">
                                        <option value="0">NO</option>
                                        <option value="1">YES</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Quantity</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Quantity" class="form-control input-md" wire:model="quantity"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Product Image</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="file" class="input-file" wire:model="image"/>
                                    @if($image)
                                        <img src="{{$image->temporaryUrl()}}" with="120" />
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Category</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <select class="form-control" wire:model="category_id">
                                        <option value="">Select Category</option>
                                        @foreach ($categories as $category)
                                            <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is caused by this :

You use, in all the function `$Product`, but in this line  `$product->SKU = $this->SKU;` you are using `$product`.

Edit this :

```
$product->SKU = $this->SKU;
```

through :

```
$Product->SKU = $this->SKU;
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Im appreciated for you advices. i fix it. and pass the problem. thanks